# Enable UnityScript from C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am trying to figure out how I can enable and disable a UnityScript (Plates_p) which is attached to my main camera from another C# script. I have tried this:

```
Camera.main.GetComponent<Plates_p>().enabled = false;
```

This throws this error: The type or namespace name `Plates_p' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

I have also tried this:

```
Plates_p myscript;
```

This throws the same error? How do I solve this?

Any help is appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's not that easy and it's recommended (or rather just much easier :) ) to only use one language. You can't access the other script directly but you can use sendMessage. With that you could create a trigger method that switches the state of your Plates_p in order to do something or don't. I don't think you can reanable it through the use of sendMessage, but I'm not sure though.

Here you can read about accessing scripts in different languages:
  http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/23274-Mixing-C-and-Javascript-how
  http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Component.SendMessage.html